# Node needs save -> edit -> save to fill all fields

Tags: nodes, entities, tokens

I have a Drupal node form with fields that depend on each other.

1 - first field (text) takes data (using default value and tokens) from other fields

2 - second field takes data from the first field (it's a geofield which geocodes from text field)

The problem is, that on hitting "save", only first field shows data. To fill second field, I need to hit "edit" and than "save" again.

Is there a way to fill both fields on one "save"?

Will appreciate any guidance.

Comment: your question not so clear to answer, if the second field takes data from the first field and first field takes data from the token, why don't you use token directly on the second field ?